# How to test angular $destroy in controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, jasmine, karma-runner

I have controller that listens for the destroy event, I cannot figure out how to test this event.

Anyone know how to test destroy?

In controller:

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
    //does something
});
```

In tests:

```
beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $injector) {
    rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
    scope = $rootScope;
}));

it('should do something when scope $destroyed', function () {
    //how to trigger the destroy event listened for in controller?
    expect(somefunction).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Thank-you

Comment: You do not have to test destroy(i.e destroy event calls destroy handler ) as a part of your application. This is a part of angular implementation and it has already been tested.

Comment: Thanks PLS, I wanted to test this handler to assert the calling of other functions from within destroy...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have not tried it, but scope has a function `$destroy()`. Call this before doing a assert.

```
it('should do something when scope $destroyed', function () {
    //how to trigger the destroy event listened for in controller?
    scope.$destroy();  // created somewhere before each test
    expect(somefunction).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Comment: Thank-you, I tried that but the controller's handler doesn't seem to get called. I updated the question adding my before each. Is that how we are supposed to create the scope?

Comment: Don't use $rootscope as scope. Try `scope = $rootScope.$new()` and where is the controller creation code. Are you passing in the scope object there?